# JQuery Filter Gallery: Combine Two Filters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, filtering

I am building a gallery of informative cards, with two filters. One filter is for day and the other filter is for category. The content of the page should change according to the user's choice.

The filters are currently working independently, and I don't know how to combine them for a seamless filtering experience.

The first glitch, happens when you pick both "Focus on People" and "Any Day". You'll have to click the buttons a few times to see the glitch. The filter doesn't display courses exclusive to "Focus on People" and "Any Day". It shows categories that should really not be there.

The second glitch, when you click "Show All", the opacity effect doesn't appear.

**JS** *For filtering the cards*

```
var $cards = $('.class-card');
var $dayFilters = $('.dayFilter');
var $categoryFilters = $('.categoryFilter');
var $noResults = $('#noResults');

// Show all days on page load 
$cards.show();
// Hide the no results message
$noResults.hide();

$categoryFilters.on('click', function(e){
  var $category = $(e.target);

  $categoryFilters.removeClass('selected');
  $category.addClass('selected')

  filterCards();
});

$dayFilters.on('click', function(e){
  var $day = $(e.target);

  $dayFilters.removeClass('selected');
  $day.addClass('selected')

  filterCards();
});

function filterCards () {
  $cards.show();
  $noResults.hide();

  var $day = $dayFilters.filter('.selected');
  var $category = $categoryFilters.filter('.selected');
  var filterClasses = [];

  if ($day.length) filterClasses.push('.'+ $day.data('target'));
  if ($category.length) filterClasses.push('.'+ $category.data('target'));

  if (filterClasses) {
      var filter = filterClasses.join('');

      $cards.not(filter).hide();

      if (!$cards.filter(filter).length) {
        $noResults.show();
      }

  }
}
```

**JS** *For opacity effect on buttons*

```
// By default, "View All" is the active button
$('#buttonAll').addClass( 'ACTIVE' );
$('#button1').addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
$('#button2').addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
$('#button3').addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
$('#button4').addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
// When user chooses, "buttonAll", make it stand-out
$('#buttonAll').click(function() {
    $('#buttonAll').removeClass( 'PASSIVE' ).addClass( 'ACTIVE' );
    $('#button1').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button2').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button3').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button4').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );    
});
// When user chooses, "button1", make it stand-out
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#buttonAll').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button1').removeClass( 'PASSIVE' ).addClass( 'ACTIVE' );
    $('#button2').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button3').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button4').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );    
});
// When user chooses, "button2", make it stand-out
$('#button2').click(function() {
    $('#buttonAll').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button1').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button2').removeClass( 'PASSIVE' ).addClass( 'ACTIVE' );
    $('#button3').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button4').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );    
});
// When user chooses, "button3", make it stand-out
$('#button3').click(function() {
    $('#buttonAll').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button1').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button2').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button3').removeClass( 'PASSIVE' ).addClass( 'ACTIVE' );
    $('#button4').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );    
});
// When user chooses, "button4", make it stand-out
$('#button4').click(function() {
    $('#buttonAll').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button1').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button2').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button3').removeClass( 'ACTIVE' ).addClass( 'PASSIVE' );
    $('#button4').removeClass( 'PASSIVE' ).addClass( 'ACTIVE' );    
});
```

I have the page hosted on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/OZzoLr).

Comment: Please reduce this to a sample that just shows the problem you're asking for help with, and give a clearer description of what you're trying to solve than "It isn't filtering as intended".

Comment: The last time I simplified the code, a different user asked me to show more of it. Can you take a look at the CodePen instead? Truly, if you click around you'll see the problem. Otherwise, I can't tell you what the issue is, hence why I am here.

Comment: Please revise your title to be a more informative question. Scrolling through thousands of questions, Experts in the field that can help you are bound to over look questions involving "weird" or other opinion or non descriptive based details.

Comment: Sees to be working. I click ""FOCUS ON PEOPLE" and only the elements with class "sort-button3" are shown. Can you help to demonstrate/clarify the issue?

Comment: The issue appears to be that the two filters (comptency and day) are operating independently. The value of one filter is essentially reset by the other. The solution would be to persist each filter value to a variable, and use the variables inside the `filterCards()` function. I don't have time to write an answer now, but can do later, if no-one else does.

Comment: Hi, @showdev, You have to click around a few times for the glitch to happen.

Comment: So hold on, when I answered your original question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239873/jquery-gallery-with-2-filters) to this logic, my assumption was that the user could only choose one day filter and one category filter, in combination.  Are you saying you want to let the users select multiple day and multiple category filters all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, here's a [new working CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjWerE).

What I have done is to use variables, `category` and `day` to persist the chosen category and day filter values respectively. This is instead of relying on the existence of a `.selected` class appearing on each filter element.

This has the benefit of firstly removing the need for the `.selected` classes all together, and secondly it means that your UI state isn't being persisted in the DOM itself.

I have also removed all of your code for adding and removing the `.ACTIVE` and `.PASSIVE` classes, and instead combined this with the filter `click` event listeners. It avoids the repetition and keeps everything much neater.

Finally, I've added copious comments to hopefully explain what is happening at each step so that you can learn how it works.

If you have any questions, ask.

```
// Prepare cards, filters, and no results message
var $cards = $('.class-card');
var $dayFilters = $('.dayFilter');
var $categoryFilters = $('.categoryFilter');
var $noResults = $('#noResults');

// Initialise by calling filter cards
filterCards();

// Prepare selected category and day filter values
var category = null;
var day = null;

// Bind click event to set selected category filter
$categoryFilters.on('click', function (e) {
  // Get clicked category filter
  var $category = $(e.target);

  // Deselect all categories, and select clicked category
  $categoryFilters.addClass('PASSIVE').removeClass('ACTIVE');
  $category.addClass('ACTIVE').removeClass('PASSIVE');

  // Record clicked category filter value
  category = $category.data('target');

  filterCards();
});

// Bind click event to set selected day filter
$dayFilters.on('click', function (e) {
  // Get clicked day filter
  var $day = $(e.target);

  // Deselect all days, and select clicked day
  $dayFilters.addClass('PASSIVE').removeClass('ACTIVE');
  $day.addClass('ACTIVE').removeClass('PASSIVE');

  // Record clicked day filter value
  day = $day.data('target');

  filterCards();
});

function filterCards() {
  // Show all cards and hide no results message
  $cards.show();
  $noResults.hide();

  // Reset filter classes
  var filters = [];

  // Add category and day filter classes, where selected
  if (category) filters.push('.' + category);
  if (day) filters.push('.' + day);

  // Filter cards where one or more filters selected
  if (filters.length) {
    // Hide cards that do not match filters
    $cards.not(filters.join('')).hide();

    // Show no results message if no cards are visible
    if ($cards.has(':visible').length === 0) $noResults.show();
  }
}
```